# what is better when creating new variable in a loop in c++

Tags: c++, programming-languages

What is the best way in C++ to use `std::map` in loops ?

- dynamically allocated
- stack allocated

Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  std::map<int,int>* m = new std::map<int,int>;
  //or ...
  std::map<int,int> m;

}
```

Comment: Can you please capitalize the relevant letters, add punctuation marks to your question etc., so it resembles proper English? It would help us maintain quality questions on the site.

Comment: Aside note: the namespace used in the STL is 'std', not 'stl'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid `new` unless you really need it, i.e. the variable/structure has a lifetime unrelated to any calling scope. (If it "belongs" to the calling function, return by value.)

This is clearly not such a case. The second, preferable, example is called a local variable.

I would be making a choice between

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  std::map<int,int> m;
  …
}
```

and

```
std::map<int,int> m;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  …
  m.clear();
}
```

The latter may perform better when the container is `std::vector` by reusing allocated memory. With `map` the difference is only style.

Answer (score 6):

That is not a static instance; a static instance would use the `static` keyword (and you wouldn't be creating a new one each time through the loop).

That is a local variable.

In C++, you should always prefer to use local variables over dynamic allocation wherever possible.  If you dynamically allocate an object (using `new`), then you have to remember to delete it when you are done with it and you have to jump through a lot of hoops to ensure exception safety.

Comment: It also helps avoid heap fragmentation

Comment: @Michael:  In many cases, yes, but in this case, all the nodes in the map are going to be allocated dynamically anyway, so there won't be much of a difference.